# find the mongo db unique documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection called location in mongodb. It has fields 
location:

```
 (_id,country,region,city,doctype,name)
```

There may be multiple documents( records ) with same name. I want to find all documents and select fields

```
_id,doctype,and name
```

with unique name. I am new to mongo db and please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`db.location.distinct( 'name' );`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

Answer (score 0):

Do a map reduce to count the name that are multiple:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function(){emit(this.name);},
    function(key,values){
        sum=0;
        for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
           sum+=values[i];
        }
        return sum;
    },
    {out:"count_per_name"}
);
```

This will create a collection named "count_per_name". Query that to find the names with count bigger than 1.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. Additionally the mapReduce methods run very much slower than the aggregation framework counterparts. You should be using those. See my answer.

Comment: Not the point. Learn the aggregation framework. It runs in native code and does not use a JavaScript interpreter to get the result. Running this code is much slower than the native implementation. I am commenting to you so you actually learn and understand this concept.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [**`.aggregate`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) function with the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "doctype": " $doctype",
            "name": "$name"
        }
    }}
])
```

This is kind of the equivalent of the SQL "GROUP" operator. See the [SQL TO Aggregation mapping](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the MongoDB manual for more examples.